# Ionic: $timeout action is being executed even if it is cancelled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, timer

Good afternoon,

I've been struggling with an unfamiliar problem. But first let me explain what I'm trying to achieve.

**Purpose**

What I'm trying to do is, setting a timer on each view, so if the internet connection is slow the timer calls a function which displays an ionicPopup with the question: "Would you like to refresh the view?" combined with a refresh button. When the button is clicked, the view will refresh. If the view loads in time (I've set the timer on 10000 milliseconds), the $timeout.cancel action is being called and the timer stops.

If that would be all it would be working fine at the moment.

**Problem**

If I navigate through my main pages rapidly, it looks like the timers aren't stop and the "Refresh popup" pops up on another page. That only happens when you click through at high speed. It looks like a few popup pop up at once beneath each other. I don't know what might be the problem, but I guess that the $timeout.cancel isn't being called if you navigate through the pages to quickly.

**Code**

*Service*

```
    .factory('Timer', function ($ionicPopup, $state, $timeout) {
    return {
        start: start
    };

    function start() {
        return $timeout(showPopup, 10000);
    }

    function showPopup() {
        $ionicPopup.show({
            title: 'Slow internetconnection',
            template: 'Click refresh to try again.',
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Refresh',
                    onTap: function (e) {
                        $state.reload()
                    }
                }
            ]
        })
    }
})
```

*Controller*

```
    .controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, Request, Timer, $timeout) {
    var timer = Timer.start();

    Request.execute().finally(function () {
        $timeout.cancel(timer);
    })

    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        $timeout.cancel(timer);
    });
})
```

I hope my problem is understandable.

Comment: Did you test whether the `$timeout.cancel(timer)` calls are actually called? Perhaps your code never reaches those calls. Instead of using `$destroy`, you may want to take a look at the Ionic View Events, as listed [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/).

Comment: I've tested it, but I found the problem somewhere else. It is fixed now!:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key thing to note here is:

> If I navigate through my main pages rapidly, it looks like the timers
>   aren't stop and the "Refresh popup" pops up on another page.

As you navigate through, your ionic views are created/destroyed, and therefore you lose references to `timer` objects.

So, in controllers where you are using timers, you must invalidate the timer before you leave that page. This is because timers are wrappers around JavaScript's `setTimeout` and `setInterval`, and JavaScript has method level scope that passes the method as a parameter to `setInterval` which will hold a reference to it, while your controller gets destroyed. Therefore, when you change view, although your controller instance may get removed, the timer does not.

Add `$ionicView.afterLeave` callbacks in your controllers.

```
$scope.$on("$ionicView.afterLeave", function(event, data){
   $timeout.cancel(timer);
});
```

This will cancel the timer for a particular controller, after that controller's view is dismissed.